# External ip is none after expose my service

Tags: kubernetes

I do exactly with the [kubernetes url](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html).

But the last step I can't get the external ip with the cmd: kubectl get svc nginx.

```
root@XXX:~# kubectl expose rc nginx --port=80
service "nginx" exposed

root@in28-051:~# kubectl get svc nginx
NAME      CLUSTER_IP   EXTERNAL_IP   PORT(S)   SELECTOR    AGE
nginx     10.0.0.109   <none>        80/TCP    run=nginx   5m
```

Comment: The `expose` command only works on cloud providers that support Kubernetes loadbalancers (aws, gce). Are you running on one of those?

Comment: @PrashanthB , I'm running on my machines. But in the document, it is not mentioned that just works on cloud providers. It is a local machine solutions.

Comment: Fyi if you're looking for loadbalancing on bare metal you can use https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/service-loadbalancer

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#type-loadbalancer

starts with:

"On cloud providers which support external load balancers..."

I agree we should better document which cloud providers do support this. I'll file an issue.